# Структура обобщенного метода, принимающего типы разных классов

Tags: java, generics

Интересует способ реализации обобщенного метода, который сможет принимать одно из значений:

1) Либо объекты типа `T`, ограниченные сверху классом `Number`:

```
T extends Number
```

2) Либо объекты типа `String`

Например:

```
public void getValue(List<T extends Number>, List<String>){
    // тут выполняется, например, сортировка полученного List'a
}
```

Что я предпринимал:

- Прочитал главу `Обобщения` книги Java - Полное руководство, Герберт Шилдт
- Гуглил
- Посмотрел здесь предлагаемые топики при написании заголовка к данному топику

  public static  void append(List list) {
      T elem = new T();
      list.add(elem);
  }

Что я нашёл:

- То, что в обобщенном методе можно реализовать способ, когда в качестве аргументов метода может быть два значения (в данном случае классы-наследники от `Number` и `String`), но чтобы метод смог принимать **или** `T extends Number` **или** `String` - я не смог найти. Поэтому интересуюсь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вместо `List<T> extends Number` должно быть `List<T extends Number>`, иначе получается что List наследник Number.

Comment: Ну и метод ваш принимает не один, а два аргумента, первый из которых `List<T>`,  а второй `List<String>`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, действительно, опечатка, исправил. Это понятно, что он принимает два аргумента. Вопрос в другом. Я привел, что я пробовал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я почти забыл Java, могу ошибиться. Кажется, вам нужны два метода:

```
public void getValue(List<T extends Number>){
    // 
}


public void getValue(List<T extends String>){
    //
}
```

Ну и если метод называется **get**, то он не `void`, а например `T`. Тогда хоть дженерики обретают смысл.

```
public Т getValue(List<T extends Number>){
    // 
}


public Т getValue(List<T extends String>){
    //
}
```

Comment: Хм, как вариант - перегружение конструктора.

Comment: @n199a это ж метод, а не класс. Где тут конструктор перегружать?

Comment: Кстати, насколько я помню, обычно говорят «перегрузка»

Comment: Два перегруженных метода. Я просто в голове это переношу на реализацию отдельного класса. Не уточнил.

Comment: Всё хорошо. Возник интерес первоначально - возможно ли в аргументах метода прописать это как-то без создание перегружаемых методов?

Comment: может стоит сделать две отдельных реализации, у которых будет свой дженерик ?

Comment: @n199a в аргументах метода вроде нельзя, да и это было бы плохо, потому что вам бы пришлось ещё и в коде метода объединять логику для того и другого случая. Перегрузка метода отлично работает и помогает не смешивать логику.

Comment: @keekkenen вроде бы у меня в ответе так и есть. Что вы имели в виду?

Comment: это было последнему комментарию @n119a